# Resources are not being loaded for shade plugin

Tags: java, maven-shade-plugin, fatjar

The below code is able to scan all the dependencies and load the resources when I am executing it from IntelliJ as IntelliJ resolves dependencies from the .m2 repo, but it's not able to load anything when running from the fat jar created by shade. any help?
The below code is not producing any output when executed from shade plugin, while from eclipse it is printing all the relevant properties.

```java
ClassLoader str = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

try {
  Enumeration<URL> resURLs = str.getResources("properties/sample/i18n-resources.properties");
  while (resURLs.hasMoreElements()) {
    URL resURL = (URL) resURLs.nextElement();
    System.out.println("file path : " + resURL.getFile());
  }
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("resource exception");
}
```

pom file :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <filters>
    <filter>
      <artifact>*:*</artifact>
      <excludes>
      <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
      <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
      <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </filter>
      </filters>
        <transformers>
            <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>com.sample.extract.samples.SampleClient</mainClass>
            </transformer>
        </transformers>
          <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
          <shadedArtifactId>application</shadedArtifactId>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: - Code is not formatted
- What is the result of the program? exception?

Comment: No Exception, Just that it is not able to find all the properties files including dependant jars, while with eclipse, it prints them.

Answer (score 0):

Analyze it as follows:

- remove configs such as `shadedArtifactAttached`, `shadedArtifactId`, `filters` - basically just keep transformers only. There is simple example [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ManifestResourceTransformer)
- before `try {} catch` add some directory logging - print what is in current `.` directory, print what is in `./properties` etc.

My suspisions:

- properties files are not included
- path to file is invalid (the invocation directory differs between InteliJ and running via shade)

Also if possible please attach the full code sample so anyone can download and run it